# I can't see the problem with my program's output even after 6 hours of programming

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This program processes "experimental scientific data" (it is really just integers) by first getting the quantity of data and their values, sort them in descending order, and finally summing.

The problem is for some reason the data is being zero(ed) out in the output I haven't been able to figure it out. I do believe the issue is in the sort_data function. But I could be wrong. I haven't the slightest idea why it is doing this.

This program is supposed to output like so

```
========================================================
                Program Number: 3
                Programmer: 
                PCC Course Number: CS227
========================================================
   Miscellaneous operations on your two whole numbers
This program processes experimental scientific data.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
How many data values are there (2 to 100, 0 = quit): 4

  Enter data value 1:    3

  Enter data value 2:    5

  Enter data value 3:    4

  Enter data value 4:    8


The data in descending order (with duplicates noted):
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
                           3.00
                           4.00 (duplicate)
                           5.00 (duplicate)
                           8.00 (duplicate)
                     ---------
                         20.00 total
```

But it is outputting like this

```
========================================================
                Program Number: 3
                Programmer: 
                PCC Course Number: CS227
========================================================
   Miscellaneous operations on your two whole numbers
This program processes experimental scientific data.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
How many data values are there (2 to 100, 0 = quit): 4

  Enter data value 1:    3

  Enter data value 2:    5

  Enter data value 3:    4

  Enter data value 4:    8


The data in descending order (with duplicates noted):
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
                           0.00
                           0.00 (duplicate)
                           0.00 (duplicate)
                           0.00 (duplicate)
                     ---------
                         0.00 total
```

I can not figure this out I have been trying for hours on end its 4 AM for me. I am loosing sanity. Please help I am dying.

```
/**********************************************************************/
/*                                                                    */
/* This program processes experimental scientific data by first       */
/* getting the quantity of data and their values, sort them in        */
/* descending order, and finally summing.                             */
/*                                                                    */
/**********************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>   /* printf, scanf                                 */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* malloc, free, exit(0)                         */
#include <string.h>  /* memcpy                                        */

/**********************************************************************/
/*                         Symbolic Constants                         */
/**********************************************************************/
#define COURSE_NUMBER   "CS227" /* PCC assigned course number         */
#define PROGRAM_NUMBER  3       /* Teacher assigned program number    */
#define LAST_NAME       "Lokey" /* The Programmer's last name         */
#define MAX_CHOICE      100     /* Max choice                         */
#define MIN_CHOICE      2       /* Minimum choice                     */
#define DATA_ALLOC_ERR  1       /* Cannot allocate data memory        */
#define DATA_SORT_ERR   2       /* Cannot allocate sort memory        */
#define QUIT            0       /* Program value to quit              */

/**********************************************************************/
/*                        Function Prototypes                         */
/**********************************************************************/
void print_heading();         /* Print the program heading            */
void print_instructions();    /* Prints program instructions          */
int  retrive_quantity();      /* Get data quantity                    */
void get_data(float *p_data_start, int quantity);
                              /* Get data values                      */
void sort_data(float *p_data_start, int quantity);
                              /* Sorts data in order                  */
void prints_data(float *p_data_start, int quantity);
                              /* Prints the data                      */
float sum_data(float *p_data_start, int quantity);
                              /* Sums the data                        */
void print_sum(float sum);   /* Prints data's sum                    */

/**********************************************************************/
/*                         Main Function                              */
/**********************************************************************/
int main()
{
   float *p_data; /* Points to the data                               */
   int quantity;  /* Quantity of data values                          */

   /* Prints program heading                                          */
   printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n");
   print_heading();


   /* Loops processing data until user quits                          */
   while(print_instructions(), (quantity = retrive_quantity()) != QUIT)
   {
      /* Allocate memory for the data and then aborts                 */
      /* program with errors if memory could not be allocated         */
      if((p_data = (float *)malloc(sizeof(*p_data) * quantity)) == NULL)
      {
         printf("\nError %d in main.", DATA_ALLOC_ERR);
         printf("\nCannot allocate memory for the data.");
         printf("\nThe program is aborting.");
         exit  (DATA_SORT_ERR);
      }

      /* Retrieves, sorts, and sums the data                         */
      get_data    (p_data, quantity);
      sort_data   (p_data, quantity);
      prints_data (p_data, quantity);
      print_sum   (sum_data(p_data, quantity));

      /* Releases the data                                           */
      free(p_data);
   }

   /* Thanks and says goodbye to the user                            */
   printf("\nThanks for your processing data. Have a nice day!");
   printf("\n\n\n\n\n");

   return 0;
}

/**********************************************************************/
/*                   Prints the program instructions                  */
/**********************************************************************/
void print_instructions()
{
   printf("\nThis program processes experimental scientific data.");
   printf("\n- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - ");

   return;
}

/**********************************************************************/
/*                      Retrieves  data quantity                      */
/**********************************************************************/
int retrive_quantity()
{
   int quantity; /* Quantity of data values                           */

   do
   {
      printf("\nHow many data values are there (%d to %d, %d = quit): ",
         MIN_CHOICE, MAX_CHOICE, QUIT);
      scanf(" %d", &quantity);
   }
   while((quantity < MIN_CHOICE || quantity > MAX_CHOICE) && quantity
      != QUIT);

   return quantity;
}

/**********************************************************************/
/*                       Retrieves data values                        */
/**********************************************************************/
void get_data(float *p_data_start, int quantity)
{
   float *p_data; /* Points to every data value                        */

   for (p_data = p_data_start; (p_data - p_data_start) < quantity;
      p_data++)
   {
      printf("\n  Enter data value %d:    ", (int)(p_data - p_data_start)
         + 1);
      scanf(" %f", p_data);
      if(*p_data < 0.0f)
      {
         printf("\nNegative %.2f ", *p_data);
         *p_data = -*p_data;
         printf("converted to positive is %.2f", *p_data);
      }
   }

   return;
}

/**********************************************************************/
/*               Sorts the data into descending order                 */
/**********************************************************************/
void sort_data(float *p_data_start, int quantity)
{
   float *p_data,  /*Points to the data                               */
         *p_greatest, /*Points to greatest data                       */
         *p_sort,     /* Points to sorted data                        */
         *p_sort_start; /* Points to start of data                    */

   if((p_sort_start = (float *)malloc(sizeof(*p_data) * quantity))
      == NULL)
   {
      printf("\nError %d in main.", DATA_ALLOC_ERR);
      printf("\nCannot allocate memory for the data.");
      printf("\nThe program is aborting.");
      exit  (DATA_SORT_ERR);
   }

   for(p_sort = p_data_start; (p_sort - p_sort_start) < quantity;
      p_sort++)
   {
      *p_sort = 0.0f;
      for(p_data = p_data_start; (p_data - p_data_start) < quantity;
         p_data++)
      {
         if(*p_data > *p_sort)
         {
            *p_sort     = *p_data;
            p_greatest = p_data;
         }
      }
      *p_greatest = 0.0f;
   }
   memcpy(p_data_start, p_sort_start, sizeof(*p_data) * quantity);
   free(p_sort_start); /* Release the memory allocated to the data   */

   return;
}

/**********************************************************************/
/*                      Print all data values                         */
/**********************************************************************/
void prints_data(float *p_data_start, int quantity)
{
   float *p_data; /* Points to the data                               */

   printf("\n\nThe data in descending order (wiht duplicates noted):");
   printf("\n- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");

   for(p_data = p_data_start; (p_data - p_data_start) < quantity;
      p_data++)
   {
      printf("\n                      %9.2f", *p_data);
      if(p_data != p_data_start)
         if(*p_data == *(p_data - 1))
            printf(" (duplicate)");
   }

   return;
}

/**********************************************************************/
/*                             Sum the data                           */
/**********************************************************************/
float sum_data(float *p_data_start, int quantity)
{
   float *p_data,    /* Points to the data                            */
         sum = 0.0f; /* Sum of all data                               */

   for(p_data = p_data_start; (p_data - p_data_start) < quantity;
      p_data++)
      sum += *p_data;

   return sum;
}

/**********************************************************************/
/*                          Prints the data sum                       */
/**********************************************************************/
void print_sum(float sum)
{
   printf("\n                     ---------");
   printf("\n                    %9.2f total", sum);

   return;
}
```

Comment: I do apologize, I am so sleep deprived I can barely function I'll take it down and repost it if you'll help me do it correctly. I am just trying to get some help.

Comment: Ok I'll try again thanks for your help but how do you post code in the question because I was not able to do it myself?

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661962/i-cant-see-the-problem-with-my-programs-output-even-after-6-hours-of-programmi#52661962) here to update your question.

Comment: Yeah I edited it but it has 3 down votes already and I am assuming it was because of my mistakes. So I don't think I am going to get help in time. I also added what the program is supposed to do in the question description.

Comment: Please try narrowing down your problem and only post the code that is erroneous. You can't expect us to go through hundreds of lines of code to search the relevant part. For instance, the `print_heading` surely isn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: What you should do next time, is not to stare at the code for 6 hours. Programmers tend to go blind when staring at their own code. But instead launch the code in your debugger and single-step through it for 5 minutes.

Comment: Your expected output is already wrong. You print ascending order, not descending. What is "(duplicate)" supposed to mean? There are no duplicates in your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(p_sort = p_data_start; (p_sort - p_sort_start) < quantity;
      p_sort++)
```

`p_data_start` points at a different array than `p_sort_start` so that's the bug. And you never actually copied the data from main() into the `p_sort_start` array. And additionally, you set the contents to zero inside the sorting loop, which doesn't make sense either.

I'm not sure why you need to allocate a second buffer in the first place, simply sort the array in-place.

Comment: @TLokeCraze programming should not be done under those circumstances, it yields subpar results as seen above...

Answer (score 1):

Your sort function is unnecessarily complex and buggy, as pointed out by other answers.

You can simply make your sort function as below.

```
void sort_data(float *p_data_start, int quantity)
{

   float temp;
   size_t i=0,j=0;
   for( i=0; i < quantity; i++)
   {
      for(j=0; j < quantity-i-1; j++)
      {
         if(p_data_start[j] > p_data_start[j+1])
         {
             temp = p_data_start[j];
             p_data_start[j] = p_data_start[j+1];
             p_data_start[j+1] = temp;
         }
      }
   }

   return;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's easier to work with array indexes rather than with pointer arithmetic

Comment: @TLokeCraze I am pretty sure he does not hate you, he may has strange teaching methods, but anyhow we are not here to blame people or be rude. So please refrain from such things

Comment: @TLokeCraze I hope the teacher is going to retire soon. BTW is using `*(p_data_start +j)` instead of `p_data_start[j]` authorized by the techer?

Comment: Haha me too, but yes he is a little senile.