# Segmentation fault with no output

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The point of this code is for the user to enter a quantity for how many floats they want to enter. Then, they enter in all the floats and sorts the floats. Lastly, it prints the results. The problem is, I'm keep getting a segmentation fault after I enter in the float values. I already have the libraries stdio.h and string.h on the code. They're just not shown here. Thanks!

```
int  quantity();
void getData(float *dataStart, int quantity);
void sortData(float *dataStart, int quantity);
void printData(float *dataStart, int quantity );
float sumData(float *dataStart, int quantity);
void total(float total);

int main()
{
   int quantity;
   float *data;

   {
      getData(data, quantity);
      sortData(data, quantity);
      printData(data, quantity);
      printTotal(sumData(data, quantity));

      free(data);
   }
   return 0;
}

int quantity()
{
   int choice;

   do
   {
      printf("\nHow many data values are there (2 to 200, 0=quit): ");
      scanf ("%d", &choice);
   }
   while((choice < 2 || choice > 200) && choice != 0);
   return choice;
}

void getData(float *dataStart, int quantity)
{
   float *data;

   for(data = dataStart; (data - dataStart) < quantity; data++)
   {
      printf("Enter data value %f: ", *data);
      scanf("%f", data);

   }
   return;
}

void sortData(float *dataStart, int quantity)
{
   float *data,
         *sort, 
         *sortStart,          
         *biggest;    

   for(sort = sortStart; (sort - sortStart) < quantity; sort++) 
   {
      *sort = 0.0f;
      for(data = dataStart; (data - dataStart) < quantity; data++)
      {
         if(*data >= *sort)
         {
            *biggest = *data;
            *sort    = *biggest;
         }
      *biggest = 0.0f;
      }
   }
   memcpy(data, sort, sortStart);     

   free(sort);

   return;
}

void printData(float dataStart, int quantity)
{
   float data;

   for(data = dataStart; (data - dataStart) < quantity; data++)
   {
      printf("                     %.2f", *data);
   }

   return;
}
float sumData(float *dataStart, int quantity)
{
   float *data,
         dataTotal = 0;

   for(data =  dataStart; (data - dataStart) < quantity; pdata++)
       dataTotal += *data;
   return dataTotal;
}
void print total(float total)
{
    printf("The total is : %.2f", total);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. 
With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. 
This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `float *data;` defines a pointer, which points nowhere. So the code scans to "nowhere", which in fact is an invalid memory location, so the code invokes the infamouse Undefined Behaviour. Anything can happen or not ...

Comment: I wonder why you are not using simple index based approach rather than struggling with pointers?

Comment: I believe this non buggy version of same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661962/i-cant-see-the-problem-with-my-programs-output-even-after-6-hours-of-programmi/52662500#52662500

Comment: Yeah it looks similar to it. I'll just base my code off of that. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so I was able to compile the program, but now I have one problem with the for loop in getData. Its only making me enter in one value.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
int quantity;
float *data;
{
  getData(data, quantity);
```

Passes *unintialized* `data` and `quantity` into the `getData` routine, which proceeds to try to write to `*data` (which is a separate bug -- it should be just `data`).

*No wonder* the program crashes.

First step, turn on *maximum* level of warnings for your compiler (use `-Wall -Wextra` if using GCC), and fix *all* warnings.

Comment: Did you see his `sortData` function it is unnecessarily complex and buggy.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the problem might be in sortData, but I'm not sure what's the issue